# Previewing a slim framework project with PhpStorm7 results page not found while

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, phpstorm, slim

I am trying out the trial version of `phpStorm 7` with `php 5.5.5`

When I preview the project in phpStorm ( go to index.php and click on a browser icon in top ), it opens

`http://localhost:63342/project/index.php`

And I get the *default `404` page from Slim Framework.* The `Visit Home Page` targets `http://localhost:63342/index.php/` Which results in a 404 phpstorm page.

If I open bash go to `PhpstormProjects/project/` and start the native php server `php -S localhost:80` and I goto localhost in browser. The project *works perfectly* as it should.

**I would like to be able to use phpstorms preview function instead of having to manual start the native server.**

### Project overview.

Started empty project, init composer, added `` `"slim/slim":"2.*" `` and installed. Added added index.php

---

### Structure

```
// scroll down for content...
~/PhpstormProjects/project/index.php

// location of slim
~/PhpstormProjects/project/vendor/slim/slim ...
```

---

### The content of `index.php`

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 // include composer autoload
 require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

 $App = new Slim\Slim;


 $App->get('/', function() {
   echo 'Hello SO';
 });

 $App->run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpStorm's **built-in web server** HAS to be accessed via `http://localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/rest/of/the/path/file.php` sort of URL. This is how URL builds **automatically**.

The key element here is `PROJECT_NAME` part -- this is how built-in web server detects what project you are working with (comparing to standard web server where such decision will be made based on domain name).

As I understand Slim framework simply cannot handle such URL with extra part in URL (at very least in default configuration), which is expected and understandable.

The bypass such restriction, you have to make few simple manual changes/configurations and you will be able to access your project via `http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/rest/of/the/path/file.php` URL

Let's assume that project name is **slim1**.

1. In your `hosts` file (or local DNS server, if you have one), create an entry that will point `slim1` to localhost, e.g. `127.0.0.1  slim1`

2. In PhpStorm -- create new Deployment entry (`Settings | Deployment`) of "**In Place**" type. **Mark it as Default** for this project and perform some very basic (and minimal) configuration (like, enter URL you want to use), e.g:

[image: Connection tab]

[image: Mappings tab]

3. Now, when you use `Preview file in...` or `Open in Browser` actions on index.php, it will open `http://slim1:63342/index.php` instead of original `http://localhost:63342/slim1/index.php`.

**P.S.**
This applicable to any framework not just Slim.

Comment: Hell yes. Great answer.

Comment: actully, i thought it worked, but i still had the php buildin  server running. I edited my hosts file `etc/hosts` and setup deployment exactly as you guided. I get a PhpStorm 404 page when previering, it goes to `http://slim1:63342/`. If i try `http://slim1:63342/project` it is the same 404, if i manualy type `127.0.0.1:63342` im back to the Slim 404 page. I can provide screenshots of hosts, structure, deplyments setup, browser result etc if wanted/needed

Comment: Still works here. You must be doing something wrong. Possibly port number has been changed happens if it is already occupied by another app) -- but that's rather unlikely.

Comment: I'm lunching IDE and doing right click on `index.php` and choosing `Open in Browser 'index.php' on Slim1`. It opens me `http://slim1:63342/index.php`. Now -- if I remove `index.php` from URL it still works.

Comment: thanks for taking such time and effort into helping me. I might be making a mistake, here a screenshot of the resoures. http://imgur.com/a/7vDxb#0,  comment below +1 and thanks

Comment: Well.. your project is called **getSource** and not **slim**. Domain name HAS TO MATCH project name -- otherwise how IDE must detect from what project it should serve files -- see 2nd paragraph of my answer about "key element"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40047/discussion-between-ronni-skansing-and-lazyone)